# Recurring error on xcode 5: file .h has been modified since the precompiled header .pcm was built

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is the error I get:

```
fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/16ZE17LEJCX4P/AssetsLibrary.pcm' was built
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/16ZE17LEJCX4P'
1 error generated.
```

---

So the problem is that these system .h files(ALAssetRepresentation.h in this error) get modified(not by me, at least not knowingly), I see in the finder that their modified date has been changed, and the only way to solve it is to copy them from another my old xcode directory(xcode4), as it still preserves the old modified date.

Does anyone have a hint on why these files get modified and how to prevent it? I can change them to read only but I fear that this change might just screw things even more(having a write permissions seems to the default, I've checked with other people's installations).

Thanks

Comment: I had this problem once. Got to your derived data folder and remove everything in it. and no worry the system can recreate everything in this folder

Comment: @NicolasManzini seems like it's working well, if you'd make your comment an answer I'd mark it as answered.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this problem once. Got to your derived data folder and remove everything in it. and dont worry, the system can recreate everything in this folder

Comment: Didn't work for me with Xcode 5.0.2 on Mavericks, iOS7.

Comment: This just happened to me, and I was concerned I would lose a whole day of work to this problem.  This solution ultimately worked for me; I used terminal to `rm -rf` everything in the derived data directory.  Deleting derived data via Xcode was **not** sufficient.

Comment: I deleted the .pcm in DerivedData folder that caused the problem, and also have to **clean the project** first to make Xcode recreate the file.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the pcm file

> rm
>   "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/16ZE17LEJCX4P/AssetsLibrary.pcm"

then

> Clean Project( Cmd+Shift+K)

**Problem solved**

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Error closely, it comes with the warning, as mentioned in question as well:

`After changing system header you should remove moduler cache, which resides path (in my case)` **/Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2IPA3N5W2OEZW**

What I did, (I went to extreme)

- Removed everything inside this folder. Then ran the project it had 2 errors.
- Then deep clean my code with `option + command + shift + k`

Now i was good to go. Code exicuted properly and result produced.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all folders in my ModuleCache folder (inside DerivedData). just fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the firsts options without any success. In my case it helped to erase ModuleCache, then deep clean and build. In that specific order did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

go to /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2IPA3N5W2OEZW directory and delete folder, clean & build.It works in Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 0):

If nothing at all works , just reinstall Xcode but delete everything related to Xcode before i.e. the Software and Derived Data Folder.
If you can't download it again, just copy it from someone it will work.